# python web scrape but blocked

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to do web scraping with BeautifulSoup and requests libraries but I got blocked by website.
Instead of doing copy/paste from a website , I wanted to do it automatically so I tried with Python.

I just did a

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(class_='list-xxx')
```

I was trying to understand the html and when I went back on the website,
I was blocked.

How come ?
I did not send 1000 of requests.
Does it mean we can do web scraping ?

Thanks

Comment: Some websites will block IPs associated with bots and automated scraping.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why an unknown website doesn't allow you to do this.

Comment: Look at what response body you get back. Might just be that the website requires you to have Javascript enabled, like for example Twitter.

Comment: If you are actually getting blocked, take the hint and stop trying to scrape the site.

Comment: the body has my ip and the email from the website contact. So I guess it is not possible for this web site

Answer (score 0):

This can be for many reasons. It's possible that you have moved to a country the website does not serve. Or you have violated their terms by sending too many requests.

In such cases the behavior you describe you can take what you see as an indication that the owners of the website either do not want you to scrape their information, or they assume the requests you have sent in their frequency an attempt to perform a DDoS (Distributed Denial of Service) attack.

If they do not want to allow scraping, then it's advisable to avoid doing it. However, if they do not have a problem with scraping, it's a good idea to contact them and ask them about their policy (if that's not public already) so you can comply to that and, if scraping is allowed, you can scrape the way you are not offending them.